# how many digits does R carry in a numeric calculation (how to increase number of digits in R Numeric)

Tags: r

If I do

```
126.887429023806 + 0.0120214904747417
```

in R, it returns

```
[1] 126.8995
```

Instead of `126.8994505142807417`

How do I preserve more decimals?

Comment: You could specify `digits` in `print` i.e. `print(126.887429023806 + 0.0120214904747417, digits = 16)`

Comment: so are those extra digits carried but not printed? ie if I use the result of that addition in another calculation will all 16 decimals be used?

Comment: If you want to change this behavior you can change the global `option(digitis=x)` , but it is not really recommended

Comment: According to `?print.default` `digits - a non-null value for digits specifies the minimum number of significant digits to be printed in values. The default, NULL, uses getOption("digits"). (For the interpretation for complex numbers see signif.) Non-integer values will be rounded down, and only values greater than or equal to 1 and no greater than 22 are accepted.`

Comment: You may want to read the FAQ [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/903061) to understand a bit more about how floating point numbers work under the hood, and become aware of a common pitfall.